# Do I need to install VMWare drivers to create a VMWare image using packe vmware-isor?

Tags: vmware, devops, packer

I am new to Packer and trying to build our environment from scratch automatically. I am getting below error when I try to create a VM using vmware-iso in Packer. So wanted to know if I need to install VMWare to run packer?

```
--> vmware-iso: Failed creating VMware driver: Unable to initialize any driver f
or this platform. The errors
from each driver are shown below. Please fix at least one driver
to continue:
* VMware application not found:
* VMware application not found:
* VMware application not found:
* VMware application not found:
*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have VMware installed or on the path on your host machine. You need to install VMware Workstation etc.

Comment: Marking as answer. Issue resolved after installing VMware workstation on the machine.